# Magento 2: Category name/url/desc not updating

Tags: magento2.2

Updated product category name/url/desc, cleared FPC but changes are not showing.

Running in single-store mode, flat catalog, cron indexing every minute.

Do I need to clear the flat catalog?

Comment: run the command php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: cron does that anyway but also tried manually, no change

Comment: Check, if you have selected the correct store in store config dropdown

Comment: I'm running in single-store  mode

Answer (score 0):

So turns out this was related to multi-single-store oddness. I switched to single store after I had made categories and 1 category was not inheriting it's info from the all stores view. The fix was to switch back to a multi-store environment, fix the categories and ensure they would inherit from all stores in future and then switch back to single-store.